# how to link and sync 2 html input number?

Tags: html, input

let say 2 x number1= number2 is there anyway to link this 2 with html.
for example when input number1 is 1 number 2 show 2, when input number 2 is 4 number1 show 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HQRb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply using event listeners.

```js
const firstInput = document.getElementById('1')
const secondInput = document.getElementById('2')

firstInput.addEventListener('input', ()=> {
  secondInput.value = firstInput.value * 2
})

secondInput.addEventListener('input', ()=> {
  firstInput.value = firstInput.value / 2
})
```

```html
<input id="1">
<input id="2">
```